# Scrolling infinite page with Python/PhantomJS/Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs

I'm trying to scrape this one (infinite) page (www.mydealz.de) but I cannot get my webdriver to scroll down the page.
Im using Python (3.5), Selenium (3.6) and PhantomJS.
I already tried several approaches but the webdriver just wont scroll - it just gives me the first page.

1st approach (the ususal scrolling approach):

```
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
while True:
  driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
  time.sleep(1)
  new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
  if new_height == last_height:
       break
  last_height = new_height
```

2nd approach (just pressing the down key several times and release it, tried wating inbetween presses, too):

```
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).perform()
ActionChains(driver).key_up(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).perform()
```

3rd approach (find the last element in the "scrolling list" and scroll to its view to force scrolling):

```
posts = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.threadGrid")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", posts[-1])
```

Nothing worked so far, does anybody know if there is another approach or where I made an error?

Comment: Do you have information about how many total data the page have?

Comment: How many scrolls do you want? Or how many elements do you want to collect? When do you want to stop scrolling? rather where do you want to stop scrolling?

Comment: @DebanjanB basically i want to scroll until the url is https://www.mydealz.de/?page=3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To scroll through the webpage untill `the url is mydealz.de/?page=3` you can use the following block of code :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'C:\\Utility\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe')
driver.set_window_size(1400,1000)
driver.get("https://www.mydealz.de")
while ("3" not in driver.current_url) :
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
print(driver.current_url)
driver.quit()
```

Console Output :

```
https://www.mydealz.de/?page=3
```

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm!
I got one question though: I used the line driver.execute_script() , too. But it didnt work. Is the key to success here to set the window size?

Answer (score 1):

I can see theres 1853 pages in the mentioned site. so you can iterate a loop until you reach the last page. Sleep time must above average to load each page, try with minimum 3, the more the value the less chance of not loading the data.

```
number_of_scroll = 1857

while number_of_scroll > 0:
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(3)
    number_of_scroll = number_of_scroll-1
```

Answer (score 1):

Easier than going the Selenium/PhantomJS way is to just mimic what the browser does. If you open the "network" tab in Chrome's Developers Tools you see that the browser does requests to `https://www.mydealz.de/?page=2&ajax=true` in order to achieve the endless scroll. When I copy the request as curl, limit it to the minimum it leads me to

```
curl 'https://www.mydealz.de/?page=2&ajax=true' -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest'
```

Turning this into a python script:

```
import json, requests

url = 'http://www.mydealz.de/'
headers = {'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'}

for page in range(10):
    params = dict(page=page, ajax='true')
    resp = requests.get(url=url, params=params, headers=headers)
    data = json.loads(resp.text)
    html = data['data']['content']
    # do something with html, maybe parse it with beautifulsoup
```

In addition to be much a simpler code it will be a lot faster also.